# How to snap 2D cursor to vertex in UV editor?

Tags: uv-image-editor, snapping, units

I'm in the UV Editor and I've UV-projected my object there. Now I want to move the 2D cursor to snap to any vertex of that object.

How to do it properly? I tried to turn on snap and set snap to vertex, but when I drag the 2D cursor, it won't snap at all. Snap to increment (grid) is working fine, but snap to vertex is not working . Any idea ?

Comment: Hello :). I'm afraid snapping in UV editor is still somewhat lacking. No absolute snap to grid and no snapping cursor to vertices.

Comment: But improvements have been suggested [here on devtalk](https://developer.blender.org/T78391) and here on [rightclickselect](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/vjdbbc/)

Comment: And no 'Active' element, either, which kind of breaks the grammar you get used to in the rest of the system.